# Difference in tracking debug information in GCC and OpenJDK compilers

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, jvm, compiler-optimization

I noticed that when I compile code with GCC `-Og`, gdb is often unable to tell the value of variables during breakpoints because they are "optimized out". I know that information exists in some form as the program result depends on its value.

On the other hand, I have never seen this happen with OpenJDK which is able to compile code very well both for performance and debug purposes.

Why such difference exists?

I think both compilers allow setting breakpoints at arbitrary places in the code even if the code was optimized out, inlined etc. I suspect the following possibilities:

- GCC simply tracks less information about the transformed program (but why?)
- JVM produces slower code that it's easier to track
- JVM deoptimizes (also de-inlines?) code when breakpoint is inserted
- JVM has better compiler architecture in this case
- JVM debugger is not actually tracing the process

Comment: *"never seen this happen with OpenJDK which is able to compile code very well both for performance and debug purposes"* Have you tried `-O0` (which is same as no optimization flags at all) with GCC? Maybe it'd be fast enough for you?

Comment: You can try `-O0 -g3` for zero optimization and maximum debug symbols.

Comment: Why are you comparing compilers for different languages? *"GCC simply tracks less information about the transformed program (but why?)"* - probably because you didn't make it to do so by specifying `-g3` option (`-Og` controls only optimization, not debug symbols verbosity). *"both compilers allow setting breakpoints at arbitrary places"* - please don't mix compilers and debuggers. "*I know that information exists in some form*" - not necessary,  for example you can write a rather fancy program in C++ that will be *completely* optimized out.

Comment: HotSpot JVM deoptimizes methods with breakpoints. Breakpoint events are delivered only when the method is running in the interpreter.